# Static Content Not Loading Plesk, GoDaddy, ASP.net MVC

Tags: html, css, plesk

My photos and stylesheets aren't loading. The site is otherwise functioning properly, just style-less. I initially thought this might be because I hadn't specified a MIME type, but all my references include something like "text/css." I then considered maybe an HTTP vs HTTPS issue, but the Console says nothing of the sort. Instead, it just lists:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
box.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I try to access the URLs of these stylesheets and images directly and get a 404. So I'm thinking I'm just not referencing them properly.

Here's the folder structure:

[image]

Here's my root directory:
[image]

Any insights into what the proper way to reference these files is? Shouldn't they be located at `myurl.com/Content/Site.css`?

Note that I'm on a shared hosting plan on GoDaddy so my options for changing any IIS settings may be limited.

Comment: can you take a snap shot of your web domain directory and show that?

Comment: who are you hosting with? show directory structure

Comment: I have added my root directory. The URL of the site is also up there so you can see the offending behavior if you'd like. It's hosted through GoDaddy.

Comment: Check your file permissions.  Sometimes when you upload files, the files don't automatically have read access for all groups.  Give that a shot.

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves I've tried that, but I see a message saying "This server does not support editing file permissions."

Comment: Where is your ASP.NET MVC stuff located? Is it the root of `httpdocs`?

Comment: James, yes, it’s the root of httpdocs. I.e. there’s a Models, Views, and Controllers folder inside it, among others.